# Freeswitch v1.10 on CentOS 7 - "mod_event_socket" and fs_cli error in fresh installation

Tags: freeswitch

By referring to Freeswitch page (https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/CentOS+7+and+RHEL+7), we did a fresh installation on CentOS 7.
Built the server from source code, did not change any configuration in order to test if the server starts fine.

When we start the server, in the logs we see the following error -

```
[ERR] mod_event_socket.c:2962 Cannot get information about IP address ::
```

When we use fs_cli, we get this error -

```
[ERROR] fs_cli.c:1691 main() Error Connecting []
```

Freeswitch seems to be running. netstat shows this output -
tcp        0      0 69.64.48.92:8081        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10547/freeswitch
tcp        0      0 69.64.48.92:8082        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10547/freeswitch

Please let us know what we might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

The fix was time-consuming but turned out to be simple. Our server is not based on IPv6, it is only IPv4 and so the below line in autoload_configs/event_socket.conf.xml was causing the issue.

This is applicable only for IPv6

```
<param name="listen-ip" value="::"/>
```

For IPv4 servers, it should be

```
<param name="listen-ip" value="0.0.0.0"/>
```

Once we fixed this, we could connect using fs_cli. Hope this post helps someone.